# Doctrine - memory leak with namedQuery execution?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using symfony 3.4 along with doctrine for my project. In one of the commands where I'm generating the ranking for users I've encountered potential memory leak when using namedQuery (though I might be wrong).

In each loop iteration (over 2000 records) I'm running an `EntityManager->clear()` method along with `gc_collect_cycles()` (just to ensure proper garbage collection). Although the memory usage just after 10000 iterations jump to around 500mB which is really odd as it works normally in other commands that are using queryBuilder to form queries.

I've made sure that no other code is responsible for this memory issue and extracted the execution to just fetchin results and running named query.

I've also tried disable sql logger in entity manager config but this didn't help. Anyone got ideas what could be wrong?

### NamedQuery

```sql
SELECT SUM(a.points) FROM __CLASS__ a WHERE a.user = :user GROUP BY a.user
```

### The problematic part of code (up to ~500MB):

```php
$query = $this->createNamedQuery('count_points');
$query->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
$query->setCacheable(false);

return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

### The solution w/o memory leak (up to ~60-70MB):

```php
$query = $this->createNamedQuery('count_points');
$query->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
$query->setCacheable(false);

// bypass named query execution through doctrine for memory saving
$sql = $query->getSQL();
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$user->getId()]);
unset($query);

return (int)$stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter memory problems in connection with `$query->getSingleScalarResult()`.

If I exchange `return $query->getSingleScalarResult();` by

```
$r = return $query->getResult();
return $r[0]['mysum'];
```

The leak is gone.
You have to change the query slightly and give the result a name:

```
SELECT SUM(a.points) AS mysum FROM __CLASS__ a WHERE a.user = :user GROUP BY a.user
```

Comment: Thank you for your input - the solution is perfect fine, as well as my posted example (which uses native SQL and is quite faster) - though I'm trying to find a root cause that is responsible for this problem. Did your solution (naming the column) helps with SingleScalarResult as well?

Comment: I recently found out that my leak is tied to the postgresql DBAL. A unit test on an in-memory sqlite connection did not reproduce the problem. Then I switch my production app to mysql, and also there, the leak does not appear.